# How do I return one String from Parse live query stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform

I'm using Parse live query to get an object from server. I have discovered finally that the Subscription object is a stream.

I would like a sort of Future await behaviour. I want my function to yield the result of the live query. How can I achieve this behaviour?

```
Future<String> isolateLiveQuery(String none) async {

  final LiveQuery liveQuery = LiveQuery();
  QueryBuilder<ParseObject> query = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Color'));
  Subscription subscription = await liveQuery.client.subscribe(query);

   subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.create, (value) {
    // I want to yield value 
  });
}
```

EDIT Adding compute attempt:

This does not work as intended, in main there is no await.

```
Future<dynamic> isolateLiveQuery(String none) async {
  final LiveQuery liveQuery = LiveQuery();
  QueryBuilder<ParseObject> query = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Color'));
  Subscription subscription = await liveQuery.client.subscribe(query);
  final c = Completer<String>();
  
  subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.create, (value) {
    String color;
    color = value['String'];
    c.complete(color);
  });
  return await c.future;
}
```

EDIT: Adding exact desired outcome with demo code:

So far this seems impossible to achieve using live query subscription. Does anyone have ideas of how to achieve below with live query subscription?

```
  Future<double> getRandomValue() async {
  var random = Random(2);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  return random.nextDouble();
  }

  print('one');                   // print instantly
  print(await getRandomValue());  // awaits for result
  print('two');                   // prints after result of last line
```

Comment: if it is a `Stream` it can trigger multiple values, so your `isolateLiveQuery` should return a `Stream` too, not a `Future`, or i missed something and you want to yield first `value` for example

Comment: Yes I would like to return first value, there will only be one value gotten from stream then stream and live query will be killed

Comment: so use [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) for example (or [Stream.first](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/first.html) property)

Comment: Tried compute(), either I'm doing something wrong or it does not work... I added code in edit

Comment: `void main() async {
print('one');
print(await foo());
print('two');
}

Future<String> foo () {
print('foo one');
final c = Completer<String>();
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => c.complete('foobar'));
print('foo two');
return c.future;
}`

Comment: Your code works perfectly by itself, if i apply it to mine like so `Future<dynamic> isolateLiveQuery(String none) async {

  final LiveQuery liveQuery = LiveQuery();
  QueryBuilder<ParseObject> query = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Color'));
  Subscription subscription = await liveQuery.client.subscribe(query);
  final c = Completer<String>();
  
  subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.create, (value) {
    String color;
    color = value['String'];
    c.complete(color);
  });
  return await c.future;
} ` i get null error and the print statements both execute

Comment: I think I may end up appealing to Back4App for help on this one

Comment: where is "null error"? what does a stacktrace look like?

Comment: Apologies, I had incorrect json item, correct item is `color = value['color']` not `['String']` however this code still does not await the live query and both print statements execute

Comment: Just altered the code out of the isolate and it works PERFECTLY! I'll figure this out from here, thank you very much for the help!